# Google for business - multiple locations with same phone number

Tags: google, geolocation, business

I am trying to add more than 10 locations for my business inside Google for business service. I have read that it's good to have different phone numbers for each location, otherwise Google will be confused and potentially merge listings..

That is a problem in my case, because I have only one phone number.

If my phone number is 123456789, can I trick google by entering variations of my phone number for each listing, i.e. 
for one entity 1.23456789 
for second one 12.3456789 
for third one 123.456789

as all of my location are in one country, my user will understand the number.

Will google accept it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds foolish already. Why? You used the term trick and Google in the same sentence. Google is not a fool so don't treat is as such. But more importantly, do what is right for users and not for machines. Use you mark-up as it should be. Do not worry about Google.

Here is the up-shot.

Too many people worry about SEO and Google and do really really silly things trying to push the right buttons and flip the right switches at exactly the right times so that Google will kiss them sweetly on the lips. It does not work that way with women and it does not work that way with Google.

So cut it out!

Build your site for people and not machines.

SEO is actually a really simple process. It is not as complicated as the SEO industrial complex makes it. The SEO advice is designed to fool you and take your money and keep you down and enrich the SEO "man". Rebel against the "man"! Take back your SEO. Do not give into the SEO hype. Do what is right. Do not look for a SEO 007 (Domain- Domain Authority / Optimized not Stirred.) to swing down and crash through the window with sub-machine guns at just the right second to save the seo-fatale and sweep him/her/cousin it away to a life of bliss ever-after.

Okay. I am being a bit silly, but that is the mood I am in. Do take what I am telling you to heart. Do what is right for your users. Full stop. Do not confuse them with all these weird phone numbers. That would be poor marketing especially when they want to call you and do a specific search for your phone number. Can you imagine if 123.456789 comes up as your phone number in the SERPs? Would that be helpful? No. Do what is right for users. Full stop.